# apacite doesn't show date but only n.d

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, apacite, date, bibentry

The apacite packet only shows n.d. instead of the date

Document

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
  \cite{IntroductionFPGAAcceleration2020}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  \bibliography{./bibliography/bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Bibliography entry

```
@online{IntroductionFPGAAcceleration2020,
  title = {Introduction to {{FPGA}} Acceleration},
  date = {2020-02-15},
  url = {https://www.stemmer-imaging.com/en/technical-tips/introduction-to-fpga-acceleration/},
  urldate = {2020-02-15},
  abstract = {STEMMER IMAGING Tech Tip: Learn more about FPGA acceleration and more about the ability to offload processing power from the CPU.},
  file = {C\:\\Users\\zas\\Zotero\\storage\\NM58JGYY\\introduction-to-fpga-acceleration.html},
  langid = {english},
  organization = {{STEMMER IMAGING}}
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've analysed the problem further and the problems was that in the bibtex.bib file the year field was missing. This was caused by the Zotero Better BibTex extension. You need to choose the export format BibTex instead of BibLatex.